# Kollokationen//collocations: 'Schreibweise benutzen'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I often have to describe other people's writing styles and conventions in German (I am not a native speaker). I have used 'Schreibweise benutzen' a few times in the past (e.g. 'man soll hier Schreibweise X statt Schreibweise Y benutzen'), but now I'm having doubts about whether 'benutzen' is the correct collocation.

Can anyone confirm this? What is the right way to say it?

Comment: *Benutzen* is okay. Some people prefer *verwenden* but there is no real reason to do so. They are pretty equivalent in that phrase. Oh, and you should use *man sollte* (same as the cooking recipe phrase *man nehme*) because *man soll* without the Konjunktiv form reads to me as if you have doubts yourself.

Answer (score 3):

"Schreibweise" usually refers to the spelling. If you want to suggest better collocations to the author or editor, you should use *die Formulierung* (writing style) or *der (feststehende) Ausdruck* (collocation).

> Man soll**te** hier den Ausdruck XY verwenden.
>   Hier soll**te** die Formulierung XY verwendet werden.

"benutzen" is far more colloquial than "verwenden", so the last would be a better choice.